# Extracting an associated type from a specific implementation

Tags: rust

I want to create an implementation for `FromStr` that forwards to a subtype. Right now I have this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a3f2f2b7e876d1f636aeeb7d2a1fa383&version=stable):

```
struct MyInt(i32);

impl std::str::FromStr for MyInt {
    type Err = std::num::ParseIntError;
    fn from_str(src: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        return Ok(MyInt(i32::from_str(src)?))
    }
}
```

But I want to specify the associated `Err` type in terms of the implementation by `i32`. I need this because I actually want to generate this code with a custom `derive`. So I can't go and look it up manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
impl std::str::FromStr for MyInt {
    type Err = <i32 as std::str::FromStr>::Err;
    fn from_str(src: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        return Ok(MyInt(i32::from_str(src)?))
    }
}
```

The `<Type as Trait>` syntax effectively lets you specify associated items (*e.g.* types and functions) from a specific type's `impl` of a trait. That means you can also write `i32::from_str` as `<i32 as std::str::FromStr>::from_str`, which might be preferable in the context of a custom derive to avoid ambiguities in case another `from_str` is in scope. For trait methods, you can also write just `FromStr::from_str` and let the compiler infer the `Self` type.